# Laravel 5 Parsedown returning plain html tags to browser

Tags: php, html, laravel, markdown, parsedown

I've installed parsedown (am using laravel 5) for parsing markdown and when I run it it is changing the markdown to html but the browser is plainly showing the parsed markdown instead of applying those particular styles for example when I run the following

`{{Parsedown::instance()->text('Hello _Parsedown_!')}}`

I expect when I run it in the browser: 
Hello *Parsedown*!

but instead am getting the following:
`<p>Hello <em>Parsedown</em>!</p>`
and when I view the browsers page source I get the following

`&lt;p&gt;Hello &lt;em&gt;Parsedown&lt;/em&gt;!&lt;/p&gt;`

What could be the problem?﻿

Comment: If you found my answer helpful then you may accept it.

Comment: Thank you so so much Pratik Soni.. It has worked!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In laravel 5 or 5.x the `{{ }}` will parse the HTML to html entities. To escape the HTML blade has provided the way which is `{!! !!}`. This will print html instead of html entities.

**So your answer will be as below**

```
{!! Parsedown::instance()->text('Hello _Parsedown_!') !!}
```

> See the Reference ( Below ) taken from [laravel official site](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-a-layout).

Displaying Unescaped Data

By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

Comment: When posting answers don't just post some code, please provide some information on why this is the solution to the question.

Comment: @Bogdan I have edited my answer as you described. If you have a moment then please have a look and let me know if it perfect or not. So i can improve it. Thanks again